ssues with ROS 2 Discovery Server: Listener Not Receiving Data from Remote Server
I am currently working with the ROS 2 Discovery Server. When I set up the server locally, both the talker and listener nodes are able to communicate and exchange messages without any issues.
However, when I set up the Discovery Server on a remote machine and configure my local talker and listener to connect through this server, the listener fails to receive any data.
What could be the cause of this issue, and how can I resolve it to enable proper communication between the talker and listener through the remote Discovery Server?
